# How to display Map Pin's of a website on the larger Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

There is a [website](http://en.villo.be/Toutes-les-stations/Map-stations#) displaying pins on a Google map included into one of its pages, but so framed that it's almost impossible to use and **print**. I'd really want to be able to make a screenshot of this map to be able to find bike-stations when I'm on my bike (without internet access). A large screenshot would be enough.

Is there a way to display those pins on the Google Maps website itself (or anyway to enlarge the Google map view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Big enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeiyV.png)? I don't have a bigger screen available right now, so that's the most I could do.

If you have a large monitor and you are comfortable with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), use it to alter the page layout and make your screen shot as big as you need.

To do that:

1. Click right close to you map
2. Click **Inspect Element**
3. Search for a `<div>` with the `id="105648"`
   [image]
4. Click on it in order to select it as in the above picture
5. In the right side you will see the CSS values for the `height` and `width` of the element[image]
6. Click on each value and alter it
   [image]
7. Close Firebug
8. **DO NOT REFRESH THE PAGE** until you are done

Comment: I want to see the complete city. I have Firebug installed. Can you guide me ? How can I change the size of this map : CSS , Html ? EDIT : OK, I got it !

Comment: Of course, this works with other browsers too; Chrome and Safari have built-in dev tools.  You should also consider using a whole-page screenshot extension like [this one for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) that lets you capture the page as if the whole thing was visible on your monitor at the same time.

Comment: I actually did it in Safari in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get bigger images from Google Maps, you can use **[Google Map Saver](http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver)**.

Google Map Saver (GMS) offers you an easy and free way to download big Google Maps on your PC as JPEG, PNG-8, PNG-24, BMP or Targa files. GMS is light (only ~400 KBytes) and very easy to run since doesn’t have an installer. You can save (and print) maps up to 12000 x 12000 pixels!

[image]